# Is there a way to combine multiple FileFilters?

Tags: java, java-io, apache-commons-io, filefilter

Is there a way to combine multiple [FileFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html)s of java.io?

```
    FileFilter wildcardFileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*.yml");
    FileFilter isFileFileFilter = FileFileFilter.FILE;

    File[] listFiles = dir.listFiles(???);
```

Answer (score 4):

What about...

```
FileFilter combinedFilter = f -> wildcardFileFilter.accept(f) && isFileFileFilter.accept(f);
```

If you want it fluent, then remember that a `FileFilter` is essentially a `Predicate<File>`, which offers some methods to combine stuff...

```
Predicate<File> wildcardFileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*.jml")::accept;
Predicate<File> isFileFileFilter = FileFileFilter.FILE::accept;

FileFilter combinedFilter = wildcardFileFilter.and(isFileFileFilter)::test;
```

Comment: Seems works but I am thinking of a more elegant fluent builder solution or similar if exists.

Comment: Added one, but honestly, I don't see the point. You could of course create something like that espcially for FileFilter, but what for? Would be easy enough to extend the interface to add some fluent default methods, for example `MyFileFilter.and(...)`, but I doubt it will add much clarity.

Comment: Thanks, it's smart and helped a lot, I am waiting some for other answers also.